# Register a Plugin on a Entity when a Solution is imported in Microsoft Dynamics 365 CRM

Tags: c#, plugins, dynamics-crm, microsoft-dynamics

I have a use case in Dynamics CRM, where there is a Plugin inside a solution. Once the solution is imported successfully, the Plugin must be automatically registered to a particular Entity.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: quick question, you want this to happen when you import solution to target env (ex: import to test env) and you are importing solution via website?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

using web you have the option when you import solution as below

[image]

If you wish to do it programatically

You need to set the property `PublishWorkflows` to `true`

```
ImportSolutionRequest request = new ImportSolutionRequest();
request.PublishWorkflows = true;
```

Answer (score 1):

I might be missing something, but as far as I understand, you should add `Sdk Message Processing Steps` to your solution, and when importing, check `Enable any SDk message processing steps included in this solution`
Obviously, you also need proper `Plug-in Assembly` added to this solution.

This will cause to plugin and steps be deployed with solution.